# Selectable image item in jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

All, I am trying to implement selectable image list . below is what I have done .
But I have two problems need to be fixed , please help to review it .thanks.

1. I don't want the the img to be selected.
2. prevent the multiple select.

**Script**

```
function initSelectable() {
$("#layoutol").selectable({
    stop : function(event, ui) {
        var result = $("#spanSelectedLayout").empty();
        $(".ui-selected", this).each(function() {
            var index = $("#layoutol li").index(this);
            result.append((index + 1));
        });

    },

    selected:function (event,ui){
        //prevent the img element selected and multiple selected, the below code not make it .
        $(event.target).children('.ui-selected').children('.ui-selected').removeClass('ui-selected');
        $(event.target).children('.ui-selected').not(':first').removeClass('ui-selected');
    }
});
```

}

**Html**

```
   <ol id="layoutol">
      <li class="ui-state-default"><img alt="" src="img/A.PNG" /></li>
      <li class="ui-state-default"><img alt="" src="img/B.PNG" /></li>
      <li class="ui-state-default"><img alt="" src="img/C.PNG" /></li>
      <li class="ui-state-default"><img alt="" src="img/D.PNG" /></li>
   </ol>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this one. Very easy to integrate on your sites : 
http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/

Comment: Please post the code that's relevant to answering the question, not just a link.

Comment: @ArmanH you can view the code in the link. there are many examples in there. It looks goods. thanks!

Comment: [Read "How to Answer Questions"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 1):

All, I found a way, What I had done is below . any better way to do ? thanks.

```
selected:function (event,ui){
            $('img',event.target).removeClass('ui-selected');
            $(event.target).children('.ui-selected').not(':first').removeClass('ui-selected');
        }
```